# How do I get rid of the horizontal scroll bar when my images go beyond the page?

Tags: jquery, html, css

soo my images go beyond on the screen because I want a fullscreen slideshow and im wondering how to get rid of the horizontal scroll bar..?

```
            <div class="fadein">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title> Iamdrivingtoday.com </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mfcc.css">

<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="JqueryPlugins/jquery.vegas.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.vegas.min.css"></link>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#html{
    overflow:hidden;
}
#fadein {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}

#fadein img {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}


-->
</style>


</head>
```

as you can see there width is 1500 and I want to keep it that way so how do i get rid of the horizontal scrollbar?

```
<body>
        <div id="big_wrapper">
            <header id="top_header">
                <img src="iadt.jpg" height="100" width="300"> </img>
            </header>

            <center><nav id="top_menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="Iamdrivingtoday.com/Home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Iamdrivingtoday.com/Application">Application</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Iamdrivingtoday.com/Privacy Policy">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Iamdrivingtoday.com/ContactUs">Contact Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </nav>  </center>

                <div class="fadein">
    <img src="images/slide1.jpg" width=1500 height=308 style="position: absolute; left: -125px;">
    <img src="images/slide3.jpg" width=1500 height=308 style="position: absolute; left: -125px;">
    <img src="images/slide.jpg"  width=1500 height=308 style="position: absolute; left: -125px;">   

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();

setInterval(function () {
    $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
                             .next('img')
                             .fadeIn()
                             .end()
                             .appendTo('.fadein');
}, 4000); // 4 seconds
$.vegas('next');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Remove the `style` and `width` attributes on your images; instead, add a class  (i.e. `class="slide-image"`) and then in your CSS define it as `.slide-image{ position: absolute; left: -125px; width=1500px; overflow-x: hidden;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
body {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RQLYM/6/)**

**UPDATE**

Using `*`, `html` or `body` to hide `overflow` is generally a bad idea but this should hide horizontal and vertical scrollbars from your page.

**I would change to this:**

```
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.fadein {
    position: absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.fadein img{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
```

Please avoid using inline styling.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RQLYM/8/)**

Comment: Yes, cause it is working on JSFiddle try changing `body` with `html`

Comment: Updated answer for you

Comment: this is what is in my <head> and <body>

Comment: that is because using `*`, `html` or `body` to hide `overflow` is generally a bad idea... try this http://jsfiddle.net/RQLYM/8/

Comment: Updated answer for you

Answer (score 1):

just add this to your containing class

```
.fadein{
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

That will work

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are adding the style to the image class , you need to add the overflow to the container that has that image, that's the one that is getting bigger

Comment: this should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the `style` and `width` attributes on your images; Each image would look like this:

```
<img src="images/slide1.jpg" class="slide-image"/>
```

And then add define the class in my **CSS**

```
.slide-image{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#fadein {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**UPDATED**
Added fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eYp7F/

Comment: tried this as well did nothing but mess my whole slideshow up and start from the center of the page. thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the style attribute in you img tag, because you should style the image however you want using CSS. Your img tag should be:

`<img src="images/slide1.jpg" width="1500" height="308" />`

> `.fadein{
>   overflow:auto;}
>   img {
>   width: 100%;}`